# regex preg replace for specific names

Tags: php

I have some file names in my database that start with dot like
.file456
.file593

I was wondering how can I filter those files that start with dot in php

thanks

Comment: You won't need a regex for that. Just check for `$filename{0} == "."`. In mySQL: `SELECT ... FROM tablename WHERE filename LIKE ".%"`

Comment: What form are the filenames in when you wish to process them?  Have you extracted them from the database already and placed them in an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't need a regex for that.

Just check for

```
if ($filename{0} == ".") ....
```

In mySQL:

```
SELECT ... FROM tablename WHERE filename LIKE ".%"
```

or in the file system, using [glob](http://www.php.net/glob) like this should work:

```
glob("/path/to/dirname/.*");
```

(although this *might* catch directories as well, you may need to check for that)

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this in your initial SQL query?

```
WHERE 'columnname' LIKE ".%"
```

You may want to replace the apostrophes (') around the column name with ` characters.

If you need it in PHP then when iterating through the records, you could do:

```
if(substr($recordvalue,0,1)=="."){

//do this

}
```

e.g.

```
for($i=0;$i<$numberofrecords;$i++){
    if(substr($record[$i],0,1)=="."){

    //do this

    }
}
```

Note that the SQL alternative is much more efficient however.

If you WANT to use preg_replace to replace the starting dot (and not other dots) with something, use (eg):

```
$pattern="/^\./";
$replacement="yourstring";
$record=".file593.jpg";
echo preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$record);
// would output 'yourstringfile593.jpg'
```